# Java blocked methoded from another thread

Tags: java, concurrency

If a method is blocked at the wait statement, can another thread call the method/will the print statement be executed?
Thanks

```
synchronised test() {
sysout("not blocked");
wait();
}
```

Comment: why don't you try it?

Comment: Yes. `wait()` releases the lock / monitor. So other threads can access this method (provided the lock is *available*)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343157/static-method-behavior-in-multi-threaded-environment-in-java/ asks a similar question. See the answers there.

Answer (score 0):

A common misconception is that the the method is locked.  In fact the object `this` is locked.  This means you can have the same method being called for different objects without using `wait()`

Conversely, if one thread obtains a lock, this will exclude any other locked section in any other method for this object.

A waiting thread releases the current lock so other methods can obtain a lock on the same object.  This also means that thread must re-acquire the lock to stop waiting.